# Overlay one div on another side of div

Tags: html, css

I want to put two divs side to side but overlayed like this. I am putting this section in middle of my webpage so i cannot use top or bottom css styles after positioning absolute.

[image]

```css
div.promoBanner__container {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.promoBanner__image {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: 50%;
  width: 76.25%;
}

div.promoBanner__content {
  background-color: rgba(17, 24, 54, .95);
}

div.promoBanner__content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 42%;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 34px 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="promoBanner__container">
  <div class="promoBanner__image col-md-8">
    <!-- <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/latest_news.jpg"
        alt="SPURSNEPAL" data-set="true"> -->
    <img src="https://tot-tmp.azureedge.net/media/9833/thfc-media-header-v2.jpg?anchor=center&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=750" alt="" data-set="true">
  </div>

  <div class="promoBanner__content col-md-4">
    <a href="#">
      <h3 class="promoBanner__title">
        Latest News
      </h3>
    </a>
    <p class="promoBanner__description">
      Today's media stories brought to you by NewsNow.
      <br>
      <br> These stories have been specially selected from today's media. They do not necessarily represent the views or position of Tottenham Hotspur Football Club. For total Spurs news coverage, visit NewsNow.co.uk, the UK's #1 football news aggregator.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the additional edited portion of the question:

I want to place these two divs like below when they reach below 800 px.
[image]
I tried to achieve this design but couldnot implement. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the design shown in the image that you included, you could follow the next points :

- add `position: relative` rule to `.promoBanner__container`.
- remove the `position: absolute` rule from `.promoBanner__image` because you'll break your design as the height of `.promoBanner__container` will only be its padding as `absolute` positioning removes the element from the document flow so the `height` of the image included in `.promoBanner__container` will not be added to to `.promoBanner__container`. Doing so we'll be able to vertically center the `.promoBanner__content` element.
- vertically center `.promoBanner__content` by the help of both `top` and `transform` properties.

The next snippet will explain more how to achieve the task :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; /** padding and border are included in the width and height preventing some overflow cases (not all !) **/
}


.promoBanner__container {
  position: relative; /** add this so his children with absolute positionning are placed relative to it **/
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
}

.promoBanner__image {
  /** removed absolute position **/
  height: 100%;
  width: 76.25%;
}

/** new rules for the image itself **/
.promoBanner__image > img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.promoBanner__content {
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 45%; 
  /** change the above rules to your desired values. If no max-width is applyied, the element will have 100% of its parent's width **/
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; /** the right property is used to prevent overflowing and to position the banner content in the desired place without any hacky calculations **/
  /** next two rules are used to vertically align the banner content **/
  top: 50%;  
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 34px 22px;
  background-color: rgba(17, 24, 54, 0.95);
  z-index: 2; /** ensure it's on top **/
}
```

```html
<div class="promoBanner__container">
  <div class="promoBanner__image col-md-8">
    <!-- <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/latest_news.jpg"
        alt="SPURSNEPAL" data-set="true"> -->
    <img src="https://tot-tmp.azureedge.net/media/9833/thfc-media-header-v2.jpg?anchor=center&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=750" alt="" data-set="true">
  </div>

  <div class="promoBanner__content col-md-4">
    <a href="#">
      <h3 class="promoBanner__title">
        Latest News
      </h3>
    </a>
    <p class="promoBanner__description">
      Today's media stories brought to you by NewsNow.
      <br>
      <br> These stories have been specially selected from today's media. They do not necessarily represent the views or position of Tottenham Hotspur Football Club. For total Spurs news coverage, visit NewsNow.co.uk, the UK's #1 football news aggregator.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT :**

Per what the OP has added to his post, here's how to make the design scale when the `width` is below or equal to `800px` :

- here's where the `CSS` **media queries** comes into play.
- you have to reset some rules in order to achieve your desired task.

The next snippet contains the edited version with the `800px` breakpoint rules :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; /** padding and border are included in the width and height preventing some overflow cases (not all !) **/
}

.promoBanner__container {
  position: relative; /** add this so his children with absolute positionning are placed relative to it **/
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
}

.promoBanner__image {
  /** removed absolute position **/
  height: 100%;
  width: 76.25%;
}


/** new rules for the image itself **/

.promoBanner__image>img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.promoBanner__content {
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 45%;  /** change the above rules to your desired values. If no max-width is applyied, the element will have 100% of its parent's width **/
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; /** the right property is used to prevent overflowing and to position the banner content in the desired place without any hacky calculations **/
  /** next two rules are used to vertically align the banner content **/
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 34px 22px;
  background-color: rgba(17, 24, 54, 0.95);
  z-index: 2; /** ensure it's on top **/
}

/**
* rules to be applied when the width is less or equal to 800px. Change this per your requirements.
* some rules have to be reset in order to achieve your task.
* resize the screen to see the changes. It's better to copy the demo in a seperate file as the StackOverflow runnable snippet sandbox may not allow you to resize it.
**/

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .promoBanner__image {
    width: 100%;  /** resetting the width to 100% **/
  }
  .promoBanner__content {
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
    /** resetting the width related rules to 100% so the two sections have the same width **/
    position: relative;  /** resetting the position rule to relative so the section remains in the document flow and we're still able to use top, bottom, right and left rules **/
    top: -45px; /** moving the section a little bit to the top. Change this per your requirements **/
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); /** ressetting the transform rule **/
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding: 34px 22px;
    background-color: rgba(17, 24, 54, 0.95);
    z-index: 2; /** ensure it's on top **/
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="promoBanner__container">
  <div class="promoBanner__image col-md-8">
    <!-- <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/latest_news.jpg"
            alt="SPURSNEPAL" data-set="true"> -->
    <img src="https://tot-tmp.azureedge.net/media/9833/thfc-media-header-v2.jpg?anchor=center&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=750" alt="" data-set="true">
  </div>
  <div class="promoBanner__content col-md-4">
    <a href="#">
      <h3 class="promoBanner__title">
        Latest News
      </h3>
    </a>
    <p class="promoBanner__description">
      Today's media stories brought to you by NewsNow.
      <br>
      <br> These stories have been specially selected from today's media. They do not necessarily represent the views or position of Tottenham Hotspur Football Club. For total Spurs news coverage, visit NewsNow.co.uk, the UK's #1 football news aggregator.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

> learn more about the [`CSS media queries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Hope I pushed you further.

Answer (score 1):

`margin-top: 35px !important;` would do the work

Answer (score 1):

If `margin-left` and `margin-right` are still viable styles to use, then, you can leverage those in tandem with `z-index`.  Set the element that you want to be in the rear with a low `z-index` number like, `z-index: 5;` and the element that you want to sit in front with a `z-index: 1005;` or some other randomly large number.

Answer (score 1):

For the container:

1. I would put `position: relative;` on the parent container.

For the image:

1. `background-size` and `background-position` don't do anything without `background-image`. I would move the `<img>` tag from the HTML to the CSS.
2. I would replace `height: 100%;` with a fixed height.
3. I wouldn't position it absolute.
4. The width property is not necessary since you're using `col-md-8` (assuming you're using Bootstrap)

For the content:

1. You don't want to use `left` and `right` together. Just pick one.
2. `overflow-y: hidden;` is unnecessary unless you have a fixed height set.

[Check out this Codepen](https://codepen.io/mlhaus/pen/YoMjyz?editors=1100) and tell me if that's what you're looking for. You can comment out the borders and play around with the `top` and `left` properties of the content.